# Angular and Firestore, queries are undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs

After updating an old project's code to the lastest versions of Angular and RxJs, I did try to update the code as much as I could.

Here is basically my [old code](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/infinite-scroll-firestore-angular/)

But now I'm getting `undefined` when it comes to queries.

```js
scrollInit(chatRoomUid: string, chatType: ChatType, reverse?: boolean, opts?: any) {
    this.query = {
      path: 'chat_room_messages',
      field: 'createdAt',
      limit: 20,
      reverse: reverse,
      prepend: false,
      ...opts
    };

    return this.userProvider.user$.pipe(
      switchMap((user: User) => {
        if (!user) return of([]);

        const first = this.afs.collection<ServerChatRoomMessage>(this.query.path, ref => {
          let cRef = ref.where('usersUid', 'array-contains', user.uid);
              cRef = cRef.where('chatRoomUid', '==', chatRoomUid);
              cRef = cRef.where('chatType', '==', chatType);
          return cRef
            .orderBy(this.query.field, this.query.reverse ? 'desc' : 'asc')
            .limit(this.query.limit);
        });

        console.log(first); # The first console log

        this.mapAndUpdate(first);

        this.data$ = this.data.asObservable().pipe(
          scan((acc, val) => {
            return this.query.prepend ? val.concat(acc) : acc.concat(val);
          })
        );
      })
    );
  }
```

As you can see I call `this.mapAndUpdate(first)` with `first`

Now the `mapAndUpdate()`

```js
private mapAndUpdate(collection: AngularFirestoreCollection) {
    if (this.done.value || this.loading.value) return;

    console.log(collection); # The second console log

    this.loading.next(true);

    return collection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      tap(arr => {
        let values = arr.map(snap => {
          const data = snap.payload.doc.data();
          const doc = snap.payload.doc;
          return { ...data, doc };
        });

        values = this.query.prepend ? values.reverse() : values;

        this.data.next(values);
        this.loading.next(false);

        if (!values.length) this.done.next(true);
    })).pipe(take(1)).subscribe();
  }
```

I did two `console.log` here is the result for the [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HHM5.png) and [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkHHG.png) one they are the same but there is another `console.log` that comes from the first where everything is [undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieeSl.png).

Now, when I go to my Angular page and call the thing like in the sample of the old code above, I'm getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGPRN.png) in the console.

I tried to add as much details as I could, but I don't know what this error means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't return anything into your switchMap.

```
return this.userProvider.user$.pipe(
  switchMap((user: User) => { ... })
);
```

this switchMap operator is supposed to return something. Consider providing it, or not using switchMap.

Comment: Uhm, It seems that I don't have any console.log errors anymore but nothing appears like in the tutorial above.